# Show a notification bar in windows 8

Tags: c#, notifications, messagebox

In Windows 8, you sometimes see a notification something like when your battery is low:

[image: Windows 8 notification bar]

I have blurred out my desktop - that part isn't actually blurred on my desktop.

How can I display one of these myself in C#?